# Correctly redraw UIComponent by validateNow()

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm removing an `UIComponent` but parts of it last being visible. 
It redraws only when I move mouse around or something. I tried to do `validateNow()` on its parent, tried to do `setTimeout(validateNow, 100)` but it doesn't help. When I call it by `setTimeout` it seems these artifacts shown more rarely but it doesn't solve a problem in all cases. Please guide me someone to read about `validateNow()`, how it works and how to make these things correctly.

The code is below:

```
protected var bubble: SpeechBubble;

// creation

bubble = new SpeechBubble();
map.addChild(bubble);

//...

// removing

bubble.visible = false;
map.removeChild(bubble);
map.validateNow();
setTimeout(map.validateNow, 100);
```

map is Google Map for Flex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you're messing with the Google Maps drawing logic.  You should look at the [developer guide](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/intro.html) provided by google.  It mentions in the [controls section](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/controls.html) that to create a custom control, you need to extend `ControlBase`.

Comment: To add on this, the `Map` class isn't a normal Flex component and doesn't take in visual elements using `addChild`.  It has a set of 'adding' functionals all there in the API.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to trigger invalidation before calling validateNow().  The call to validate now causes the code to check if any of the invalidation flags are set (properties, display list, or size) then for each calls the appropriate method to correct the invalidation (commitProperties, updateDisplayList, measure) in your case it sounds like it's just not doing the clear call to the graphics or redrawing appropriately so you may need to call

```
bubble.invalidateDisplayList();
bubble.validateNow();
```

Also hope one of these solutions works out for you, generally speaking forcing validation at a given time is not usually a good idea as the framework components should trigger the appropriate invalidation and subsequent validation in it's life cycle, but I can't say I haven't done this myself :).

Shaun

Answer (score -2):

You may use **includeInLayout** property

```
bubble.visible = false;
bubble.includeInLayout = false;
```

Example demonstrates this property

[The Beauty of includeInLayout](http://flexblog.imtiyazbasha.com/2009/06/the-beauty-of-includeinlayout/)

hopes that helps

Comment: -1.  You're trying to provide a workaround (that doesn't work), not a fix. Plus, the `Maps` class doesn't use a layout.

Comment: @ J_A_X  "includeinlayout" is one of statndard property used by "mx.core.Container" and it's childs to measure layout and positon there child/UIComponent, it's NOT a "WORK-AROUND". Google's MAP class is a direct Child of "flash.display.Sprite" that why its removed, this is because they also want same SDK with flash. and I thought MAP is class of "Container"